# How to enlarge my div onClick() in my jsp file?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, netbeans

I draw 4 charts in my jsp file and I need to make them bigger when I click ;

So if you know how to do it ??

I heard that its possible in javaScript but I don't know how ??

This is my code :

```
<div id="chartContainer" style="height:270px; width:500px;margin-right: 110px" onclick="bigger()"></div>
<Script>
window.onload = function() { 


var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    exportEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: ""
    },
        axisX: {
        title: "Clients",
                  //tickLength: 0,
                  labelFormatter: function(e){
                return  "" ;
            }
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "Chiffre d'affaire annuel"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "column", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
        //showInLegend: "true",
                //legendText: "{label}",
        toolTipContent: "{label}: <strong>{y}</strong>",
        //indexLabel: "{label} {y}%",
                dataPoints: ${data}
    }]
});
chart.render();
}
</Script>
```

I want an output like this
[image: I want an output like this]

Answer (score 0):

If your CanvasJS.Chart is sized by filling the DIV container you have created then the solution would be to add an onclick listener for the DIV element and then pass a function that changes the .style.width and .style.height values.

```
let bigger = () => {
    document.getElementById("chartContainer").style.width = "800px";
}
```

Change the 800 to whatever you want and add a similar line for .height.

Comment: Can u tell me how to do it ;I'm not familiar with javascript functions

Comment: First check if changing the width and height style declarations of your div element change the size of the chart...? For example try width = 700px and see if it makes it wider.

Comment: check the edit on my answer above which shows the function you can add which gets ran whenever you click on the div area.

Comment: Yes it add width but I don't look for this output ,I want to like a dialog box that show when I click and  contain the chart